# Migrating an existing CentOS 5.x server to use Zend Server CE

Tags: migration, centos5, zend-server

I am considering upgrading my CentOS server to run PHP 5.3, and would also like to start using Zend Server CE at the same time but am new to doing it on something that isn't a fresh install.

I have a CentOS 5.x instance that, [other than using PHP 5.2](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2), is running the stock Apache packages from the official repositories. I have a few PECL modules installed (apc and imagick), and am also using mod_dav_svn.

I know how to get Zend Server CE up and running on CentOS, but have always done it from a fresh server instance and never in one that has been alive for a while.

Can I simply just backup my config files, uninstall httpd and PHP via yum, and then install Zend Server CE via the normal method?  Or will I have complications because of dependencies that have already been installed?

I am also considering spinning up a new server instance for this, but want to weigh the upgrade method against having to copy all of my data to a new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've migrated Stock CentOS servers to Zend Server CE before. I did as you described and removed apache / PHP from the server through yum and then installed Zend Server CE.  I then re-set any of the missing / incorrect PHP options and installed any PECL modules.  It went much better than expected.